# How to create generic search engine using elasticsearch?

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, search-engine

We are creating search engine for medical community where it can pull record from mongoDB. Database has records from various medical community like doctors, laboratorists, pathologists, specialists etc. We want to pull result on the basis of name, locality, equipment, time for distance (if we have location).
We are using Elasticsearch as search engine.

Update:
I think it was not specific to be answered. I went through documentation as pointed by Dennis Ich. I have completed search index as per requirement using
autosuggest, filters - ngram, fuzzy...

I am getting issue with highlight option. Here is my code:

> Blockquote

```
curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/hospital/hospitals/_search?pretty -d '{
  "query" : {
    "fuzzy" : {
        "_all" : "orthopadic"
      }
  },
  "highlight": {
    "fields" : {
        "*" : {
        "pre_tags" : ["<p>"],
        "post_tags" : ["</p>"], 
        "fragment_size" : 18
        }
    }
  }
}'
```

output:

> Blockquote

```
{
  "took" : 459,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 64,
    "max_score" : 1.8097699,
    "hits" : [ {
      "_index" : "hospital",
      "_type" : "hospitals",
      "_id" : "105",
      "_score" : 1.8097699,
      "_source" : {
        "reviews" : "283",
        "name" : "Sohandas Udbalker M Vzsuoxhmkvfgijxzzjh",
        "specialization" : "Orthopaedic",
        "recommendation" : "146",
        "seniority" : "24",
        "likes" : "218",
        "online_participation" : "58",
        "online_booking" : "810",
        "tracking_system" : "60",
        "follow_up" : "53",
        "consultation_point" : "52",
        "online_prescription" : "29",
        "patient_count" : "61",
        "health_expense" : "94",
        "location" : "bangalore"
      },
      "highlight" : {
        "_all" : [ "Vzsuoxhmkvfgijxzzjh <p>Orthopaedic</p> 146" ]
      }
```

I want to highlight specific fields. It is taking fragment number, how can we highlight specific field.

Comment: Its really unclear what you are exactly asking for. I suppose you should read the elasticsearch documentation and just start indexing your data. You will most likely find everything you need there. If you need help on a specific topic come back. If you already decided to take elasticsearch you should have at least some knowledge from evaluating?

Comment: Thanks Dennis, I went through documentation, it's really awesome and I am implementing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For creating generic search engine you have to satisfy the following requirements
1)Full Text Search--The ability to not only return documents that contain the exact keywords.
2)Clustering- Distribute the data across different nodes.
3)Horizontal Scalability- Ability to increase capacity of cluster by adding more nodes.
4)Auto Complete